# Anylogic: Counting the times an agent goes through a serviceblock to then decide if the agent should leave the system or not

Tags: anylogic

I have a serviceBlock which is connected to a selectOutput. This selectOutput is connected back to the serviceBlock (False) and to a sink (True)

I want to count the amount of times an agent goes through the service block and at 10 rounds, the selectOutput block should send the agent to sink.

My current solution:
Made a variable at the Agent type called rounds which is int with initial value 0
In the service block (on Exit): ((Agent) agent).rounds++;
in the select output i have the condition ((Agent) agent).rounds < 10

other than this condition, I want the selectoutput to send True(0,15) and False(0,85) as long as rounds < 10.

This is my first question on stack, so any errors in the formulation is on me :)

Right now I get 0 errors, but  the selectoutput does not work properly.

Answer (score 0):

Increment your counter in the 'On at exit' property of the service block instead of 'On exit'. In the second case the changes aren't registered before the agent enters the selectOutput

Comment: I tried to change it to "On at exit", still does not work properly. Do you know by any chance how I can see the value of the variable which is in agent tab? I cannot seem to find a way to monitor it to see if it updates.

Comment: Not sure what you're referring to as agent tab, but you can use `traceln()` to print the value to console, it helps most of the time